# what does formControl.value?.length do?

Tags: angular

I understand its not the best post. But I saw this line of code in the material multi select custom trigger example.

`*ngIf="toppings.value?.length > 1"`
 https://stackblitz.com/angular/omvmgjjbnnq?file=app%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.html

I don't understand what the "?" is doing here and I am having a hard time even googling what it could be (google doesn't like question marks). Does this allow you to call a property of `value` safely without having to check if `value` is defined or null?

Comment: What part of the code are you asking about? The question mark?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *ngIf="toppings.value?.length > 1"

I'll explain each part

> *ngIf

Is a conditional directive that removes the DOM element if the expression evaluates to *false*.

> toppings

Is a public property on the component.

> .value

Is a child property of the `toppings` variable.

> .value?.length

The `?` operator tells Angular to stop evaluating the expression if value of `toppings.value` is *undefined*. This prevents you from getting `length` is not a property of `undefined` errors.

> toppings.value?.length > 1

Tells `*ngIf` to keep the DOM element when `toppings.value` is not *undefined* and `toppings.value.length` is greater than `1`.

### Safe Navigation Operator

That is what the `?` mark is called.

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

It's also a really bad name, and why you couldn't find any Google results for it.

Comment: this is one of those times... where I wish I had of known about this 6 months ago lol. Would have saves so many `*ngIf="toppings && toppings.value && toppings.value.length"` type conditions. Thanks

Comment: You and me both. This is one of those *must know* feature which isn't really explained quick enough in the docs. I think I used Angular 2 for about a year before I learned of it.